# Register filter for an area

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Is there a way to register filter for specific area?

For example below code register Authorization Filter globally(force to authenticate):

```
services.AddMvc(config =>
{
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                     .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                     .Build();
    config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
});
```

I want this but only for some areas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a custom `IFilterProvider` which can create the filter dynamically.

Example:

```
public class CustomFilterProvider : IFilterProvider
{
    public int Order
    {
        get
        {
            // This value is fine. The `DefaultFilterProvider` has an order of `-1000` and so is run before this provider.
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public void OnProvidersExecuted(FilterProviderContext context)
    {
    }

    public void OnProvidersExecuting(FilterProviderContext context)
    {
        var controllerActionDescriptor = context.ActionContext.ActionDescriptor as ControllerActionDescriptor;
        var controllerType = controllerActionDescriptor.ControllerTypeInfo;

        var areaAttribute = controllerType.GetCustomAttribute<AreaAttribute>();
        if(areaAttribute != null && areaAttribute.RouteValue == "Admin")
        {
            var filter = new TestAuthorizationFilter();
            context.Results.Add(new FilterItem(new FilterDescriptor(filter, FilterScope.Global), filter));
        }
    }
}
```

Register the provider in DI:

```
services.TryAddEnumerable(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<IFilterProvider, CustomFilterProvider>());
```