# How to handle errors differently for (or distinguish between) API calls and MVC (views) calls in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, error-handling, asp.net-core-mvc

In my applications based on ordinary MVC and WebApi I had two different error handling routes.

If an error occurred during WebApi call, I would intercept it (using standard web api options) and return json message with corresponding HTTP Status Code so that client app can handle it.

If the error happened in MVC, then I would use some standard handlers that would redirect user to some default error screen possibly based on status code.

Now in ASP.NET Core both are joined in the same framework, so if I just intercept and return JSON, then I risk showing json to a user, since it can be an action that returns a view. On the other hand if I use `app.UseExceptionHandler` then my API calls would get HTML from the error page that is unusable inside js.

What is the good way to provide separate error handling for this two cases? Or perhaps there is a better way to handle it altogether?

P.S. I would rather reuse the MVC exception handler that comes out of the box and only add the web api part.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There are many ways to achive your goal:

**1- Using two different exception filter**(i would go with this approach because your question is about mvc pipline)

Implementation:

```
// For api
public class ApiExceptionFilterAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        // send error as json
    }
}


[ApiExceptionFilter]
public class ApiController : Controller{...}

// For mvc
public class MvcExceptionFilterAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        // send view result
    }
}


[MvcExceptionFilter]
public class HomeController : Controller{...}
```

If you want to add filter globally, see [Register filter for an area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39036165/register-filter-for-an-area)

**2- Using `UseWhen` and `UseExceptionHandler`**

```
         app.UseWhen(x => x.Request.Path.Value.StartsWith("/api"), builder =>
         {
             builder.UseExceptionHandler(new ExceptionHandlerOptions()
             {
                 ExceptionHandler = async (ctx) =>
                 {
                     var feature = ctx.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
                     var error = feature?.Error;
                     // send json
                 }
             });
         });
        app.UseWhen(x => !x.Request.Path.Value.StartsWith("/api"), builder =>
        {
            builder.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        });`
```

**3- Using `UseExceptionHandler` conditionally:**

```
        app.UseExceptionHandler(new ExceptionHandlerOptions()
        {
            ExceptionHandler = async (ctx) =>
            {
                if (ctx.Request.Path.Value.StartsWith("/api"))
                {
                    var feature = ctx.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
                    var error = feature?.Error;
                    // send json
                }
                else
                {
                    // redirect error page
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for comprehensive answer. Point number 2 seems most interesting to me, since it allows using standard handling for both MVC and ExceptionHandler, which is in a way similar to the approach in previous version and seems rather logical. I would think though that it's possible to use option 3 with some "skip handling" that will use the default registered UseExceptionHandler().

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, there's an option #4 too. `services.AddController(opts => { opts.Filters.Add(new YourApiExceptionFilter()); }); services.AddMvc(opts => { opts.Filters.Add(new YourMvcExceptionFilter()); });`.

Comment: I tried option #2 in asp.net core 6.0 and it doesn't work! The non-api handler is invoked. It is really weird.

Comment: ok, I got it working properly by placing the non-api `UseWhen` second instead of being called first. I hope this will save some poor soul time. Honestly, so finicky!

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to write your custom middleware to handle exceptions as want.
An example here:

```
public class ErrorMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate next;

    public ErrorHandlingMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            await next(context);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await HandleExceptionAsync(context, ex);
        }
    }

    private static async Task HandleExceptionAsync(HttpContext context, Exception exception)
    {
        if (exception == null) return;

        var code = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;

        if (exception is MyNotFoundException) code = HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
        //here you can check what kind of exception it is

        //wite is proper for Web API, but here you can do what you want
        await WriteExceptionAsync(context, exception, code).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    private static async Task WriteExceptionAsync(HttpContext context, Exception exception, HttpStatusCode code)
    {
        var response = context.Response;
        response.ContentType = "application/json";
        response.StatusCode = (int)code;
        await response.WriteAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new 
        {
            error = new
            {
                message = exception.Message,
                exception = exception.GetType().Name
            }
        })).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

And this is how you can register your middleware:

```
app.UseMiddleware(typeof(ErrorMiddleware));
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, but if I understand correctly this will override all the MVC exception handling as well, so if the user goes to /notExistingController or I have a bug in the View, he'll get a JSON exception back?

Comment: This will be a custom middleware so if you will detect (depending on anything you want) that it's a MVC exception then simply skip middleware and move to next on in the pipeline.

Comment: So that's quite the question here: how do you detect it?

Comment: You detect it by only catching the exceptions you want to handle with your code. The rest is just forwarded to the next middleware. This means you need to do a proper exception handling, creating custom exceptions for the cases you want your middleware to handle.