# Different exception and error views for different areas in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In ASP.NET Core's `Startup` class, exception handling and error views are defined like this:

```
app.UseExceptionHandler("/error");
// ...and later on...
app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/error/{0}");
```

However that applies to all areas. In our pre-Core project, each area had its own exception and error views (isn't easy, but can be done).

How do I do that for ASP.NET Core?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40149061/how-to-handle-errors-differently-for-or-distinguish-between-api-calls-and-mvc/40153711#40153711 It might be useful.

Comment: @ademcaglin Looks interesting, thanks.