# Exception handling using Hellang middleware in .Net Core MVC

Tags: exception, asp.net-core-mvc, middleware

I've used [Hellang](https://github.com/khellang/Middleware) Middleware for exception handling as the global exception handling mechanism in my MVC application.
I've added the following code in the ConfigureServices method in Startup.cs:

```
services.AddProblemDetails(opts =>
            {
                // Control when an exception is included
                opts.IncludeExceptionDetails = (ctx, ex) =>
                {
                    // Fetch services from HttpContext.RequestServices
                    var env = ctx.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IHostEnvironment>();
                    return env.IsDevelopment() || env.IsStaging();
                };
                opts.ShouldLogUnhandledException = (ctx, e, d) =>
                {
                    return (d.Status.HasValue && d.Status.Value >= 500);
                };
            });
```

Also I've added `UseProblemDetails()` in Configure method.

However I came to know that if am using `UseProblemDetails()`, then `UseExceptionHandler()` won't work!
Hence I'am not able to figure out a method for navigating user to a common error view page.

Is there any way to redirect users to an error page while sticking on to Hellang Middleware for exception handling and logging ?

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem. I solved it like the following. In this example logging a custom business fault exception:

```
services.AddProblemDetails(setup =>
{
    setup.Map<FaultException<BusinessFault>>((context, exception) =>
    {
        // resolve logger
        var logger = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ILogger<ProblemDetails>>();

        // log exception to Seq
        logger.LogError(exception, "{@Exception} occurred.", exception);

        // return the problem details map   
        return new ProblemDetails
        {
            Title = exception.Message,
            Detail = exception.Detail.FaultMessage,
            Status = exception.Detail.FaultType.ToHttpStatus(),
            Type = exception.Detail.FaultType.ToString(),
            Instance = exception.Detail.FaultReference
        };
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

See the answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/40153711/90287

You have to distinguish between the type of request, if it's an API request or a UI request to determine if a problem+details JSON should be returned or if a web page should be returned, respectively.

This is what I do near the top of the `Configure` method of `Startup.cs`:

```
app.UseWhen(context => context.IsApiRequest(), branch =>
{
    branch.UseProblemDetails();
});

app.UseWhen(context => !context.IsApiRequest(), branch =>
{
    branch.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
});
```

You can define your own custom HttpContext extension method:

```
public static class HttpContextExtensions
{
    public static bool IsApiRequest(this HttpContext context)
    {
        return context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
            || (context.Request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest"); // AJAX request
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is not exactly the answer to your question, but I had a similar issue in a Web API application regarding using ExceptionHandler middleware and Hellang ProblemDetails Middleware and I also came to realize I could't use them both because both change the response in their own way and affect one another.

Based on the documentation [here](https://github.com/khellang/Middleware/blob/master/src/ProblemDetails/ProblemDetailsMiddleware.cs) you can use one of the configuration options of the ProblemDetails package to excute code before changing response and there you can log all the information you need.

```
services.AddProblemDetails(options =>
        {
            options.IncludeExceptionDetails = (context, ex) =>
            {
                var environment = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IWebHostEnvironment>();
                return environment.IsDevelopment();
            };

            options.Map<IdentityException>(exception => new ProblemDetails()
            {
                Title = exception.Title,
                Detail = exception.Detail,
                Status = StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError,
                Type = exception.Type,
                Instance = exception.ToString()
            });

            options.OnBeforeWriteDetails = (ctx, pr) =>
            {
                //here you can do the logging
                logger.LogError("Exception Occurred!!!!");
                logger.LogError(pr.Detail);
                logger.LogError(pr.Instance);
            };
        });
```

Here, I use a custom exception with extra fields that are needed for problem details object in response, and I use the Instance field to hold the exception and log it.

Comment: where are you magically getting logger from?

Comment: You have access to IServiceCollection here, so you can build ServiceProvider and resolve the logger from DI container.